# javascript regex search and find

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to check if a string contains [suggestion=mixofnumberandcharacter]

But im not sure how to do that, anynumber will of course be any number or character.

and, how do i after that get the suggestion mixofnumberandcharacter id?

Comment: `/\[suggestion=\d+\]/.test(yourStringVar)`

Comment: @PranavCBalan could you explain how do use it?

Comment: `if(/\[suggestion=\d+\]/.test(yourStringVar)){   }`

Comment: what is the test containing? and string?

Comment: to get the id value...  `yourStringVar.match(/\[suggestion=(\d+)\]/)[1]`

Comment: how do i do it to also allow characters ( with numbers) ? @PranavCBalan

Comment: `yourStringVar.match(/\[suggestion=([\da-zA-Z]+)\]/)[1]`

Comment: dont you mean [0] ?

Comment: the captured value present at index `1` and entire string match at `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
var str = "asd asd asd asd [suggestion=mix0fnumb3r4ndch4racTeR] sd  asd asd sd";
var found = str.match(/\[suggestion=([0-9A-Za-z]*)\]/);
console.log(found);
```

The console output will be:

```
Array[2] {
    0        : "[suggestion=mix0fnumb3r4ndch4racTeR]"
    1        : "mix0fnumb3r4ndch4racTeR"
    index    : 16
    input    : "asd asd asd asd [suggestion=mix0fnumb3r4ndch4racTeR] sd  asd asd sd"
    length   : 2
    __proto__:    Array[0]
}
```

So what you are looking for is `found[1]` which is matched by the `()`. Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/85jy3suu/3/).

Comment: I know it is a trivial question/answer but why the -1? It is a starting point for @maria to look into the code, console and fiddle...